# How to access the formControlName of a nested FormGroup inside a FormArray

Tags: angular, form-control, formarray, formgroups

I might be totally wrong with the way I'm managing the form and the information here. If so, I'm sorry everyone but I'm kind of lost here...

Here's my form:

```
private tpForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [null, Validators.required],
    vat: [null, Validators.required],
    activityNumber: [null],
    addresses: this.fb.array([
      this.createAddress()
    ])
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  createAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      street: [null, Validators.required],
      streetComp: [null],
      streetComp2: [null],
      city: [null, Validators.required],
      cp: [null, Validators.required],
      state: [null],
      country: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

**important side-note:**

1. the form is private
2. there's a constructor in there

**because it comes from a service that generates the form** which is adapted for different models.
But you get the idea of the overall structure of the form.

**My objective is to be able to add more than one `address` if necessary and each `address` is a `FormGroup` Object because it is, in itself, sort of a form.**

the thing is, I can't seem to access the controls included in the FormGroup, itself nested in the FormArray:

```
<mat-card-content>
      <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="1.2:1">
        <form [formGroup]="tpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <mat-grid-tile formGroupName="tpForm"> //<--- Here I'm trying to divide the access to the controls (name, vat, activityNumber) this one gives me an error (see below)
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Customer VAT Number</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="vat">
              <mat-error *ngIf="tpForm.get('vat').invalid">Please enter a VAT number!</mat-error>
              <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="tpForm.get('vat').valid || !editing">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Customer's local VAT number</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
            <button style="margin: 0.5rem;" mat-raised-button type="button" color="accent" (click)="onLoadInfo()" [disabled]="tpForm.get('vat').invalid || !editing">Load information</button>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Customer name</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="name">
              <mat-error *ngIf="tpForm.get('name').invalid">Please enter the customer's name</mat-error>
              <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="tpForm.get('name').valid || !editing">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Has to match the customer full legal name</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Customer Activity Reference</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="activityNumber">
              <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="tpForm.get('activityNumber').value">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Customer's local activity reference (INSEE, CNAE...)</mat-hint>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile formGroupName="tpForm.get('addresses')[0]">//<--- So that I can get the controls from the addresses here 
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Street</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="street">
              <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="tpForm.get('addresses')[0].get('street').value">sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
              <mat-hint>Customer's local activity reference (INSEE, CNAE...)</mat-hint>
           </mat-form-field>
         </mat-grid-tile>
       </form>
  </mat-grid-list>
</mat-card-content>
```

For now, not I'm not too surprised about it. All this yields on the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'tpForm'
```

Pointing to the line in my code (see the comment) `<mat-grid-tile formGroupName="tpForm">`

I'm a bit lit lost in translation and would love your input on how to handle this.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form [formGroup]="tpForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <mat-grid-tile formGroupName="tpForm">
```

That is wrong, since you don't have any form group named "tpForm" inside the main form group named "tpForm". Remove that useless `formGroupName="tpForm"`.

```
formGroupName="tpForm.get('addresses')[0]"
```

That is wrong, too. tpForm.get() returns a form control. You must pass the **name** of a form group to `formGroupName`.

You need something like

```
<div formArrayName="addresses"> <!-- addresses is the name of the form array inside the owning form group tpForm -->
    <div [formGroupName]="0"> <!-- 0 is the index of form group inside the owning form array addresses -->
        <input formControlName="street"> <!-- street is the name of the form control inside the owning form group 0 -->
```

Comment: looks so simple... and yet I was so far from the solution. Thanks @JB Nizet!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a 'tpForm' member that is inside of your FormGroup. which doesn't have that.

```
 this.fb.group({
**tpForm : this.fb.group({}),** //if you had this it would work.
name: [null, Validators.required],
vat: [null, Validators.required],
activityNumber: [null],
addresses: this.fb.array([
  this.createAddress()
])
```

});

You need to understand that without brackets formGroupName = "string"  angular considers the input is plain string. With brackets [formGroupName] = "objectFromComponent" angular will consider that input coming from a component object.

For FormArray I would suggest check angular guide they explains what you want to achieve very well.
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-defining-a-formarray-control